# Sorting 3 numbers c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm supposed to write a function that takes `3` integer parameters and rearranges them. 
For example, if `a=370`, `b=2105`, `c=40` then the function should result in `a = 2105`, `b=370`, `c=40`.

My code is giving me

> errorLNK201` unresolved external symbol and fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a, b, c;
void sort_three (int & a, int & b, int & c);
void main () {}
void sort (int & a, int & b, int & c) {}
```

Thank you!
I realized sort and sort_three didn't match, that solved it, thank you all

Comment: That's some  weird brace style.

Comment: Surely the error message said more than that. In particular, it gave the name of the missing symbol, which is how you can tell what's missing.

Answer (score 9):

The names don't match in:

```
void sort_three (int & a, int & b, int & c);
void sort (int & a, int & b, int & c) {
```

The former is clearly meant to be a prototype for the latter, but it has the wrong name.

The sorting algorithm also isn't quite right (for starters, it has undefined behaviour in `r[i+1]`).

Answer (score 2):

Rename

```
void sort (int & a, int & b, int & c) {
```

to

```
void sort_three (int & a, int & b, int & c) {
```

Linker errors always occur when linker fails to find enough information to link the function call with function definition.

Function signature in prototype should match with the function signature in definition. And should be called with the same signature too.

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't your "void sort" be "void sort_three"? (would help to see the precise link error though)

Answer (score 1):

You declare sort_three `void sort_three (int & a, int & b, int & c);` but define sort `void sort (int & a, int & b, int & c) {` thus there is no sort_three in your program.